# Getting `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` when running Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, import, jestjs, syntax-error

I'm trying to run a test using Jest, and so I'm importing the following at the top of my test file:

`import { describe, it, expect } from '@jest/globals'`

However, when I run the test, I get the following error: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fix it. Instead, just use the CommonJS form of the statement at the top, as follows:

`const { describe, it, expect } = require('@jest/globals')`